# I am having issues aligning my "calculate btn" to the center on mobile

Tags: html, css

I am having issues allinging my "calculate btn" to the center on mobile

Please I am confused, my "calculate button", I am not able to align it to center on mobile view

I tried making use of the align center attribute but it failed

On mobile view, the calculate button shifts to the right, Please this my first time working pure css, thank you.

```css
.calculate-button {
  /* margin-top: 7px; */
  width: 50%;
  margin: 20px 0;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background-color: #7e1c1c;
  margin-left: 127px;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(185, 23, 23);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!----Calculate---->
<div class="calculate">
  <small id="error"> error message</small>
  <div class="calculate-button">
    <!-- onClick event function -->
    <button class="btn" onclick="lovecal()">Calculate Love(%)</button>
    <!-- End onClick event function -->

    <!-- Added images -->
    <!-- <img src="images/love2.jpg" id="image1" alt="" /> -->
    <!-- <img src="images/love2.jgp" id="image2" alt="" /> -->
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <!-- <img src="images/love2.jpg" alt="" /> -->
    <!-- <div class = "input-heart"><i class="fas fa-heart fa-4x "></i></div> -->

    <h2 class="heading">45</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of the `.calculate-button` to 100% and use `text-align: center` to center its content.
And for the `.btn` class, we're setting its display to `inline-block` and its width to 50% so that it fits in the center of the `.calculate-button`.

```css
.calculate-button {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background-color: #7e1c1c;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```